# NativeScript. Add new layout when a tap event occurs on actionItem element

Tags: javascript, nativescript, bindable

i tried creating an app that allows me to add my new pet's name and color whenevr i click on add new page, but the app is not working as i expect it, i need help, i am kinda stuck. On tapping the add a page, it navigates to a page to fill a form and then binds the details back to the main page, but it is not just obeying .[when i click, a new layout is added[it navigates to the form page[instead of returning back to the main page with two layout, i am getting one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUqWX.png)

Comment: You might want to use a ListView, that's good for performance at same time you just have to push the new item to array that's in bound with ListView, so it renders the new item automatically.

Comment: Yeah, that's the prob. The liewView ui is not appealing to me. I want an app whereby the info are displayed with layouts and users can check by clicking on each layouts rather than picking out of a list

Comment: Your screenshot looked like it should be good with ListView. Still if you want to dynamically add / remove layouts, use the addChild / removeChild method. You will find [examples here](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/layouts)

Comment: Alright,, thanks man